# Multiple queries or a single query returning multiple tables when binding data to ASP.NET controls?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

ASP.NET controls don't let you specify a table index to use when binding a data source, so your query can really only return a single table if you're using a SqlDataSource control to handle your data.  The alternative would be to run the query from the codebehind and databind manually.  Either method is fine with me really, but I'm curious what (and why) the "best practice" is in this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get multiple sets of 'needed' data using one query, its always preferable PROVIDED you really need the data. Yout 2nd approach gives you that flexibility

Also, using a `SQLDataSource`, in any real life production application would be against most best practices as it combines your DAL with your UI. There is absolutely no concept of layering when doing it in this manner and you are in effect making a 1 layer application. 
Dont use a `SQLDataSource` would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're experience performance problems, I'd look at your stored procs, your database, or your network configuration. There's nothing wrong with making multiple calls to the database for the purpose of accessing concise and modular data. In fact, you can hurt performance a lot more by coming up with really expensive queries just to reduce your number of queries.

If you are accessing the same data for many different functions in your application, then you can pull the data to your Cache and query the cache instead of the database. This will have a far greater impact on performance than reducing the number of queries.

Comment: I'm not experiencing any problems, I'm still in the planning stages of my project and this is something I've wondered for some time.  Thanks for the reply!